# How is the metric space on $[0,1]$ open in itself?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $([0,1],d)$ be a metric space. A set is said to be open iff for every element in the set there is some epsilon ball, containing the element, that lies withing the set. $[0,1]$ is said to be open within itself;

How can I possibly find an epsilon ball around the points $0$ or $1$? What's wrong here?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: In that case $B(a,r)=\{x\in [0,1] : |x-a|<r\}$.

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to see this way: open sets in $[0,1]$ are the intersections of open sets in $\Bbb R$ with $[0,1]$. In particular, $[0,1]=\Bbb R\cap [0,1]$.

Comment: You need to regard “balls” in the relative space as truncated balls in the absolute space. That is, to have a relative ball around $0$ in $[0,1]$, take $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, which is a ball in the absolute space $\mathbb R$ around $0$, and cut off the part that doesn't belong to $[0,1]$. Thereby you get $[0,\varepsilon)$, which is considered as a ball in the relative space.

Comment: Ok, the truncated balls makes more sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are viewing $[0,1]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, so we are looking at the the subspace metric topology, i.e any open set intersected with $[0,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$.  So about the point $0$ take $r=1/2$ and $B_r(0)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x-0|<r\}$.  Then

$$B_r(0)\cap[0,1] $$

is an open set under the subspace metric topology and contains the point $0$.  The same can be done with the point $1$.  Also, the whole subspace $[0,1]$ is open in itself since, taking $r=2$, we have

$$[0,1]=B_r(0)\cap[0,1] $$ 
for example ($r=2$ was arbitrary, I just needed a big enough radius to encompass all of $[0,1]$).  Hope that helps!